# I want to lock the keyboard except Y/N in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is what I have so far, I'm a novice or intermediate at best.
I want to only allow the Y/N keys to work and to enable the keyboard you would press CTR + ALT + M I guess, the enable key be anything.

```
@ECHO OFF
echo I know I have two bsod.hta, it wasn't a mistake

echo Beginning of the script 
;start "" "RougeDetection"
;start "" "bsod.hta"
;start (keyboard lock here)

:VBSDynamicBuild
SET TempVBSFile=%temp%~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%":ECHO OFF


;ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
;ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
;ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{F11}"                            >>"%TempVBSFile%
;ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

:choice
set /P c=Will you stop taking over my computer?[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :BeGone
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :YouAI
goto :choice

:BeGone
echo "I'm sorry, I don't  want you here anymore"

echo This is a 2 second delay timer
;ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul

echo BSOD.hta is a window that fullscreens and has a full black background and is good at hiding the screen, it blacks out the screen but you can easily get past it by pressing ALT + TAB or WIN key or ALT + F4
;start "" "bsod.hta" 

echo Im using RAT and letting people use my computer, and some people go rouge 
:taskkill /F /IM AnyDesk.exe /T

echo This locks my computer, it basically pressing WIN+L but it uses |rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation| and its a separate bat file
;start "" "Lock.bat"

:exit

:YouAI
;start "" "bsod.hta"
;start "" "Lock.bat"

:exit
```

Comment: Please don't deface questions, even your own.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all of this:

```sh
:choice
set /P c=Will you stop taking over my computer?[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :BeGone
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :YouAI
goto :choice
```

with just this:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /M "Will you stop taking over my computer"
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo YouAI
```